# Is a Pushdown Automata possible for this language?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

PDA for a Language L = { $a^i b^j \mid i \neq 2j+1 \}$ over the Alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$

If it can be constructed, how?

**Edit** : I've tried make the PDA for $$L = \{ a^i b^j \mid i = 2j+1 \}$$ (with the intention of editing the PDA to accept if $a$ or $b$ is leftover) but can't figure out how to push the proper number of $a$'s.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Perhaps start by trying to construct a PDA for $\{a^nb^m:n\neq m\}$.

Comment: Note that in general, it is not possible to complement PDAs (since CFL is not closed under complementation). So it is not entirely clear that a PDA for $\{a^ib^j:i=2j+1\}$ would help. But still, it's a possible starting point. Recall that you can push multiple $a$'s without reading anything from the word, as this is allowed in PDAs. e.g. have $\delta(q,\epsilon)=(q',a,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Just push one $A$ for every $a$ you have. Then delete the proper number of $A$'s for each $b$.

Comment: @Shaull For the $\{a^nb^m:n\neq m\}$ I believe [this](http://imgur.com/wC1IVWY) is a solution. How does this help my problem, though? I can only apply this if I can accept the proper number of $a$'s.

Comment: As @HendrikJan said above: first push $A$ for every $a$ you see.  Then, every time you see $b$, remove two $A's$ from the stack. When the $b$'s end, try to remove one additional $A$, and see if the stack is exactly empty (e.g. by pushing some initial symbol before reading anything).

Comment: @Shaull I devised a probable solution to the question. Is [this](http://imgur.com/VdQyTQV) the correct PDA?

Comment: You seem to be popping only one $a$ for every $b$. You should be popping two.

Comment: Another possible way to think about it is this: $x \neq y$ implies that either $x <y$ or $x > y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction for PDA will be as follows :

1) Push all $a's$ into stack

2) For every $b$ pop two $a'$ from stack, continue this till all $b$ exhaust
there will be three condition for acceptance -

1) If stack got empty before $b$ exhaust

2) If stack got empty and $b$ exhaust

3) If there exist more than one $a$ in stack after $b's$ exhaustion.

else REJECT.